# Gutenberg cannot seem to find TextControl

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I have include @wordpress/components in my build. (I ran npm install wordpress/components and see it in package.json)

I import the TextControl thus: `import {TextControl} from "@wordpress/components";`

But at this line I see in the console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'TextControl')

I am using wordpress-scripts package. Obviously I am missing a step.

What might it be?!

Answer (score 2):

There were various problems but the main one I was not loading the dependencies that the wp-scripts build puts into a file with the name pluginname.asset.php. For example;

`<?php return array('dependencies' => array('wp-components', 'wp-element'), 'version' => '123');`

and in your wp_enqueue_script script call you have to send these dependencies as a parameter.

`wp_enqueue_script('name', 'path.js', $script_asset['dependencies'], $script_asset['version']);`

It looks like Gutenberg uses this to decide which bits of itself to load. They are not included the built js file.

Comment: Try using [npx @wordpress/create-block](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-create-block/) when setting up a new block project; this will ensure that all the required dependencies are loaded and built and help you avoid this issue.